# Is there any way to optimize this SELECT query any further?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that is filled with mails from a postfix mail log. The table is updated very often, some times multiple times per second. Here's the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output:

```
Create Table postfix_mails CREATE TABLE `postfix_mails` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `mail_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
 `host` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
 `queued_at` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'When the message was received by the MTA',
 `attempt_at` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'When the MTA last attempted to relay the message',
 `attempts` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `from` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `to` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
 `source_relay` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `target_relay` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `target_relay_status` enum('sent','deferred','bounced','expired') COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
 `target_relay_comment` varchar(4098) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
 `dsn` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
 `size` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `delay` float unsigned NOT NULL,
 `delays` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
 `nrcpt` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `mail_signature` (`host`,`mail_id`,`to`),
 KEY `from` (`from`),
 KEY `to` (`to`),
 KEY `source_relay` (`source_relay`),
 KEY `target_relay` (`target_relay`),
 KEY `target_relay_status` (`target_relay_status`),
 KEY `mail_id` (`mail_id`),
 KEY `last_attempt_at` (`attempt_at`),
 KEY `queued_at` (`queued_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=111592 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci
```

I want to know how many mails were relayed through a specific host on a specific date, so I'm using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM `postfix_mails`
WHERE `queued_at` LIKE '2016-04-11%'
  AND `host` = 'mta03'
```

**The query takes between 100 and 110 ms.**

Currently the table contains about 70 000 mails, and the query returns around 31 000. This is only a couple of days' worth of mails, and I plan to keep at least a month. The query cache doesn't help much because the table is getting updated constantly.

I have tried doing this instead:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM `postfix_mails`
WHERE `queued_at` >= '2016-04-11'
  AND `queued_at` < '2016-04-12'
  AND `host` = 'mta03'
```

But the query takes the exact same time to run. I have made these changes to the MySQL configuration:

```
[mysqld]
query_cache_size = 128M
key_buffer_size = 256M

read_buffer_size = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4096M
```

And confirmed that they are all in effect (`SHOW VARIABLES`) but the query doesn't run any faster.

Am I doing something stupid that makes this query take this long? Can you spot any obvious or non-obvious ways to make it faster? Is there another database engine that works better than InnoDB in this scenario?

---

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) as `count`
    -> FROM `postfix_mails`
    -> WHERE `queued_at` >= '2016-04-11'
    ->   AND `queued_at` < '2016-04-12'
    ->   AND `host` = 'mta03';
+----+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys            | key            | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | postfix_mails | ref  | mail_signature,queued_at | mail_signature | 92      | const | 53244 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+--------------------------+----------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) Also check MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Please show us the EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM `postfix_mails`
WHERE `queued_at` >= '2016-04-11'
  AND `queued_at` < '2016-04-12'
  AND `host` = 'mta03';

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza MySQL doesn't have `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` AFAIK, but I added the `EXPLAIN` output

Comment: @BerndBuffen Added

Comment: @Hubro - add a index. your query dont use a good index and try again : ALTER TABLE `postfix_mails` ADD KEY host_queued_at (`host`,`queued_at`);

Comment: if MySQL version is less then 5.7 , disable the query cache.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I stupidly thought that having 2 separate indexes (one for `host` and one for `queued_at`) would be almost as good as having both columns in a single index. That was very wrong though. After adding the index as you suggest, the query now takes around 30ms.

Comment: the reason is that MySQL only (mostly) can use 1 index in one Operation. so its mostly better to have a composite index with the fields used in WHERE and the sequence of the fields is: put this field a the first position that reduce the result most. You can check the Work with EXPLAIN ....

Comment: Other Options are: Try to use a compressed connection between Client and server. If you return many rows it safes much time. Or if you have very large tables use partioning. So you the table look as one but the stored in pieces ie. month or something else. so a query only looks in this pieces from the hole table

Comment: @Hubro - try with normal mysql client : mysql -hxxx -uxxx -p   -C      --,        -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.

Comment: @BerndBuffen This query just returns a single row with a single value, so compression shouldn't make a difference. I will start testing out partitioning when the table starts growing really big though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your query to be really fast, you'll need to materialize it.

MySQL lacks a way to do that natively, so you'll have to create a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE mails_host_day
        (
        host VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        day DATE NOT NULL,
        mails BIGINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (host, day)
        )
```

and update it either in a trigger on `postfix_mails` or with a script once in a while:

```
INSERT
INTO    mails_host_day (host, day, mails)
SELECT  host, CAST(queued_at AS DATE), COUNT(*)
FROM    postfix_mails
WHERE   id > :last_sync_id
GROUP BY
        host, CAST(queued_at AS DATE)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE  mails = mails + VALUES(mails)
```

This way, querying a host-day entry is a single primary key seek.

Note that trigger-based solution will affect DML performance, while the script-based solution will result in slightly less actual data.

However, you can improve the script-based solution actuality if you union the most recent actual data with the stored results:

```
SELECT  host, day, SUM(mails) AS mails
FROM    (
        SELECT  host, day, mails
        FROM    mails_host_day
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  host, CAST(queued_at) AS day, COUNT(*) AS mails
        FROM    postfix_mails
        WHERE   id >= :last_sync_id
        GROUP BY
                host, CAST(queued_at) AS day
        ) q
```

It's not a single index seek anymore, however, if you run the update script often enough, there will be less actual records to read.

Answer (score 2):

`queued_at` is a datetime value.  Don't use `LIKE`.  That converts it to a string, preventing the use of indexes and imposing a full-table scan.  Instead, you want an appropriate index and to fix the query.

The query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM `postfix_mails`
WHERE `queued_at` >= '2016-04-11' AND `queued_at` < DATE_ADD('2016-04-11', interval 1 day) AND
      `host` = 'mta03';
```

Then you want a composite index on `postfix_mails(host, queued_at)`.  The `host` column needs to be first.

Note:  If your current version is counting 31,000 out of 70,000 emails, then an index will not be much help for that.  However, this will make the code more scalable for the future.

Comment: Oddly your query still takes the exact same time to run as mine, which is between 100 and 110 ms. I'm guessing yours will be faster when the row count gets up to tens of millions though. I was hoping there was a way to get it to run in 10 ms or less. I have dealt with much more complicates tables with lots of relations and joins and millions of rows that ran huge queries in a couple of ms. I was using SQLite3 at the time though, not MySQL.

Comment: @Hubro add an index, as Gordon suggested. You appear not to have one.

Comment: Check sum(host) and sum(queued_at) with your conditions.

put the more selective (less sum) as the first in the composed index

Comment: @ninjabber: the one on `queued_at` will be more selective, but putting it first kills performance. That's not how the ranged queries work.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I doubt we can be sure about the performance before having a look at the cost in both cases and no way we know which is more selective.
Should I never use the ranged column in the beginning of a composite index?

Comment: @ninjabber: with an equality condition on `host` and ranged condition on `queued_at`, `(host, queued_at)` will always be at least not less selective than `queued_at` alone. You can use the ranged column in the beginning of a composite key, but the rest of columns are not ordered anymore and will only serve as covering.

Comment: @Hubro . . . Aggregating 31,000 rows takes some time, even if the data is already in memory.  As the data gets larger, though, the amount of time should negligibly increase -- with the right indexes (or partitioning if you used that).

Answer (score 0):

You have a unique key on 'host', 'mail_id', and 'to', however when the query engine tries to use that index, you aren't filtering on 'mail_id' and 'to', so it may not be as efficient.  A solution could be to add another index just on 'host' or add `AND 'mail_id' IS NOT NULL AND'to' IS NOT NULL` to your query to fully utilize the existing unique index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pagination to speed up queries in PHP which is usually how I resolve anything that contains a large amount of data - but this depends on your Table hierarchy.

Integrate your `LIMIT` in the SQL query.

**PHP:**

```
foreach ($db->Prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`
FROM `postfix_mails`
WHERE DATEDIFF(`queued_at`, '2016-04-11') = 0)
AND mail_id < :limit "))->execute(array(':limit' => $_POST['limit'])) as $row)
{
    // normal output
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var starting = 1;
    $('#next').click( function() {
        starting = starting + 10;
        $.post('phpfilehere.php', { limit: starting })
            .done( function(data) {
                $('#mail-output').innerHTML = data;
            });
    );

);
```

Here, each page shows 10 emails on, of course you can change this and modify it and even add a search which I actually have an Object I use for all my Projects.

I just thought I'd share the idea - it also adds real-time data flow on your site too.

This was inspired to me by Facebook's scrolling show more - which really isn't hard but is such a good way for querying a lot of data.